# OrientDB Schema changes from java session dont appear in console.sh session unless I reconnect

Tags: session, schema, orientdb

If I open a connection to a OrientDB database from console.sh, then I use  separate Java code to add a class, the class does not show in the console session ("list classes") unless I reconnect.

Why are schema changes not universal?  Does this mean different clients will see the same database differently?

Just to clarify - Im not asking for a workaround, Im asking "WHY" does this behaviour exist, the answer Im looking for will explain the "WHY".

Answer (score 5):

when logged in the database from your console, try the following command:

```
reload schema
```

It should reload the schema, and if you list the classes again, you should see the new classes imported.

Comment: As @cgull asked: "Does this mean different clients will see the same database differently?"  Apparently, your answer is "Yes, until the schema is reloaded."  What if changes are made to the data (by the Java program) using the changed schema?  What if changes are made to the data by the console.sh session?

Comment: this is a showstopper for me.  I cant have my code do a reload schema before every single database read.  I have data coming in with new fields that I cant predict hence my choice of OrientDB for its flexible schema.  Im very dissapointed with this find.  Is there a reason for this behaviour?